# How do I generate a level randomly?

Tags: java, android, platform, auto-generate

I am currently hard coding 10 different instances like the code below, but but I'd like to create many more. Instead of having the same layout for the new level, I was wondering if there is anyway to generate a random X value for each block (this will be how far into the level it is). A level 100,000 pixels wide would be good enough but if anyone knows a system to make the level go on and on, I'd like to know that too. This is basically how I define a block now (with irrelevant code removed):

```
block = new Block(R.drawable.block, 400, platformheight);
block2 = new Block(R.drawable.block, 600, platformheight);
block3 = new Block(R.drawable.block, 750, platformheight);
```

The `400` is the X position, which I'd like to place randomly through the level, the `platformheight` variable defines the Y position which I don't want to change.

Comment: A `for` loop and some `Math.random()` calls. Did you try googling for it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering that each block needs to be further than the previous one,

```
List<Block> blocks = new LinkedList<Block>();
Random rnd = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());

int x = 400;

while (youNeedMoreBlocks)
{
    int offset = rnd.nextInt(400) + 100; //500 is the maximum offset, this is a constant
    x += offset;                         //ofset will be between 100 and 400

    blocks.add(new Block(R.drawable.block, x, platformheight));

    //if you have enough blocks, set youNeedMoreBlocks to false
}
```

But this looks overly simplistic to me. Either i didn't understand your question or it actually was  that simple.

Edit:

For assignments like these:

```
block.setY(three_quarters - 10); 
block2.setY(three_quarters - 10); 
block3.setY(three_quarters - 10);
```

You need to modify the loop with:

```
List<Block> blocks = new LinkedList<Block>();
Random rnd = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());

int x = 400;

while (youNeedMoreBlocks)
{
    int offset = rnd.nextInt(400) + 100; //500 is the maximum offset, this is a constant
    x += offset;                         //ofset will be between 100 and 400

    Block tmp = new Block(R.drawable.block, x, platformheight);
    tmp.setY(three_quarters - 10);                 
            //do with tmp everything you need to apply to each block

    blocks.add(tmp);

    //if you have enough blocks, set youNeedMoreBlocks to false
}
```

Another wise idea would be to generate the blocks on demand when the player is close to the edge of the map, so you have faster loading times.

Comment: This looks very good and was my question, although what do ido to this block.setY(three_quarters - 10);
  block2.setY(three_quarters - 10);
  block3.setY(three_quarters - 10); i dont mean about random the y axis but i mean the assignment block, block2, block 3??

Comment: @CharltonSantana rather than having 3 individual variables for blocks, have a list with all them. Why 3? later on if you want 4, you need to add another variable, initialize it, etc. Using a list is way more dynamic. For the setY part, i'm editing the answer.

Comment: i dont know how to initalise it ... are you able to tell me.. i also have a collsion detection which is annoying because if i want 100 block i have to copy and past then edit 100 times(like you said) here is part of the collision for block 2 ..  // bottom left touching block?
   if (sprite.bottomlx < block.bottomrx && sprite.bottomlx > block.bottomlx && sprite.bottomly < block.bottommy && sprite.bottomly > block.topry ){
    Log.d(TAG, "Collided!!!!!!!!!!!!1");
    
      
   }

Comment: Here to add more blocks i would have to change eg block.topry to block2.topry

Comment: @CharltonSantana initialize what? If you want 100 blocks random, then have a list with all them, why 100 hardcoded lines? For collision just use the same list and work with that. Maybe you should delve a little more on programming before taking such a difficult challenge as game programming is (no offense)

Comment: sorry i ment different instanses of an object not initilize lol .. and im not having 100 lines of code anymore... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10091089/generating-bimaps-with-the-instance-title-different-everytime